# Codeigniter -> user-membership

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm using this: https://github.com/alvariux/codeigniter-user-membership would a addons for codeigniter that allows registration, login and all user management. I loaded in my server codeigniter, properly installed and loaded also the folder "application".

Once launched the website, the message standard welcome.

```
Welcome to CodeIgniter!

The page you are looking at is being generated dynamically by CodeIgniter.

If you would like to edit this page you'll find it located at:

application/views/welcome_message.php
The corresponding controller for this page is found at:

application/controllers/welcome.php
If you are exploring CodeIgniter for the very first time, you should start by reading the User Guide.
```

I tried to do some editing to launch other files "view", but nothing gave me 404 error.

I explained what to change?

Comment: Step three in the link you provided states: "You will find an example of usage under controllers/membership.php".... Have you had a look at that?

Comment: I wouldn't use this library as it offers **no** security features whatsoever. It will do more harm than good.

Comment: I'm using Ion Auth, I think it is safer and better. Unfortunately I have the same problem. example.com/index.php/create_user and not: exmple.com/create_user.php

Answer (score 0):

check routes.php on config .

```
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');
/*
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| URI ROUTING
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| This file lets you re-map URI requests to specific controller functions.
|
| Typically there is a one-to-one relationship between a URL string
| and its corresponding controller class/method. The segments in a
| URL normally follow this pattern:
|
|   example.com/class/method/id/
|
| In some instances, however, you may want to remap this relationship
| so that a different class/function is called than the one
| corresponding to the URL.
|
| Please see the user guide for complete details:
|
|   http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html
|
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
| RESERVED ROUTES
| -------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| There area two reserved routes:
|
|   $route['default_controller'] = 'welcome';
|
| This route indicates which controller class should be loaded if the
| URI contains no data. In the above example, the "welcome" class
| would be loaded.
|
|   $route['404_override'] = 'errors/page_missing';
|
| This route will tell the Router what URI segments to use if those provided
| in the URL cannot be matched to a valid route.
|
*/

$route['default_controller'] = " ";//<-USE WHAT U WANT DEFAULT PAGE
$route['verify/(:any)'] = "/action/verify/$1";
$route['404_override'] = '';


/* End of file routes.php */
/* Location: ./application/config/routes.php */
```

Answer (score -1):

This is my first time that I use codeigniter, I checked the file but I see no education.

I would just figure out how to display the various pages in index.php

Comment: You should use the comments feature to reply to other members

Comment: work through the blog tutorial in the codeigniter manual. in terms of auth libraries use something that is actively maintained. ion auth is highly recommended.